# Are hard items heavier than 2 kg forbidden to be placed in carry-on luggage in flights within Mexico?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, mexico, electronic-items

I have the following massager that I  sometimes bring in my carry-on luggage:

[image]

Product dimensions: 4 x 5 x 5 inches. Weight: 4.2 Pounds.

Massagers are in the list of permitted items for the TSA (https://www.dhs.gov/learn-what-i-can-bring-plane), though as usual the final decision lies in the hand of the security agents.

As I was  taking a flight within Mexico for Christmas, the TIJ
departure airport security refused me to  keep it in my carry-on luggage. The reason I was given was that I could use it to kill someone on my way to MEX  since it was hard and heavy. I had to go back to the airline check-in desk to have it placed as a checked in luggage. It's the  first time I had this issue with this massager, however this was also the first time I flew within Mexico.  There was some language barrier between the security staff and myself, and the check-in desk was about to close, so I couldn't ask for more information.

Was that security staff overly paranoid or is it typical for hard items heavier than  2 kg to be forbidden to be placed in carry-on luggage in flights within Mexico?

My carry-on luggage weight was lower than what I was authorized (15kg), so this wasn't some overweight issue.

Comment: Being overly paranoid is typically a requirement to get a job as the security officer...

Comment: Any solid heavy item can be classed as a blunt object which is a forbidden carry on item category in probably all countries. The definition of "blunt object" is subjective and would be left to the wisdon of the officer manning the checkpoint.

Comment: @RedBaron Thanks, does that mean they could refuse a laptop if they feel like it?

Comment: You could test by carrying a heavy laptop next time ;)

Comment: @RedBaron I do typically carry a heavy laptop (> 2kg). I'm now also getting overly paranoid. Anyway, you're welcome to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I can't find releavnt sources ATM for an answer but I did find [contact for authorities in Mexico for defining dangerous goods](https://www.icao.int/safety/DangerousGoods/Pages/NationalAuthority.htm#Mexico). Maybe you can drop a mail and post an answer if you receive a reply

Comment: @RedBaron thanks, great link, I've just emailed them. I'll let you know if I hear back from them.

Comment: They can pretty much refuse anything they want. I've been yelled at  for items that are explicitly legal and allowed, but there is simply no point in arguing. They have the final say, regardless of what they official rules say. They also have all day to discuss this, while you have a plane to catch.