Airport security confiscated umbrella
I have an umbrella with a pretend samurai sword handle made of plastic that I carry on my backpack. Security let it through for my flight from LAX to NRT. On the way back, NRT security cited the handle as prohibited and I was forced to give it up.
Why the discrepancy and could I have argued a case to keep it?


Airport security rules / interpretation thereof vary. What passes in LAX isn’t necessarily going to get through elsewhere.

@NeanDerThal clearly not always given LAX let it through.

Arguing with airport security is rarely a winning strategy, and can backfire badly,.

@DavidRecallsMonica agree which is why I didn't. Just annoyed now at the discrepancy.

Several years ago, I was annoyed at a seemingly teen-age sneering security person in Paraguay who took a small pair of scissors I'd carried overseas and back for decades. It happens.

Scissors could constitute as weapon. Umbrella... I guess if you're John Wick.

Blunt instruments capable of doing damage are banned: coshes/batons and baseball bats unsurprisingly, but Ryanair claims tennis racquets too. How solid is the handle? Also, it looks quite short, but the usual cabin baggage size limits will apply.

Solid enough for an umbrella. If it didn't have the fake samurai engravings, they would've let it go so it's just annoying.

@DavidRecallsMonica It would help if there was better recourse in the event of an unfair confiscation other than complaining to the airport or TSA authority and hoping they'll give you some compensation. If it's a cheap novelty item it's easy to shrug off but what if it was far more valuable?

Sorry for your loss. I'm neither a weeb nor a weapon fetishist but that's a pretty cool umbrella.

@DavidRecallsMonica i had the same frustration, a small pair of scissors that were definitely below the regulated blade length, that I'd carried all over the world, were confiscated in AMS as a security person decided they were too long. I tried briefly to argue but they just threw them in the bin and told me to move along, I was brick-walled on the matter. Absolutely nothing you can do, just very frustrating

@Crazymoomin last time that happened to me (https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/171441/1810), I packed the item at some airport baggage wrapping shop and I sprinted back to the check-in counter to add it as a check-in luggage about 1 minute before the counter closed. Definitely very annoying and frustrating.

@FranckDernoncourt Ouch, that must have cost nearly as much as the item is worth.

@Crazymoomin Luckily, that was free except for the cheap baggage wrapping, otherwise I would have thrown it on some security heads to verify their claims. Air travel is such a pain unless one doesn't care about time and money.

First, each country (or group of countries, sometimes) sets its own rules for security. While they more or less align because they generally follow the same objective, there is no obligation for them to be the same everywhere. Japan and the US can have different rules, and you can't do anything about that.
Next, rules are not always applied consistently and extensively. They are human, they miss things. Frequent travellers have lots of stories of the forgotten Swiss Army knife or screwdriver somewhere in their bag which went through a dozen flights and as many security checks in different countries before someone finally noticed it and confiscated it (for an item that is nearly universally banned). Different scanner technologies may also have an influence, as well as training.
In this specific case, there may also be a cultural aspect: a Japanese agent is more likely to recognise a samurai sword handle than a US agent.

Exactly! To me, this looks like an umbrella handle. To a typical Japanese person, it looks like a sword handle.

I am from the UK and this definitely looks like a sword handle to me.

Even aside from “they are human, they miss things”, any real-world set of rules is inevitably going to have borderline cases that come down to a judgement call, which can reasonably be decided differently by one agent than another.  And “lookalike items” is an obvious source of borderline cases — obviously realistic replica weapons can’t be permitted, obviously sufficiently unrealistic ornaments are harmless, but somewhere in the middle each agent has to make a judgement call.
